# change the total everyday with +1 when the day is changes

Tags: php, mysql, date

My current output:

```
+--------------+---------------
    date       |   total
+--------------+---------------
  6/5/2015     |      0
  7/5/2015     |      0
-------------------------------
```

The correct output should be:

```
+--------------+---------------
    date       |   total
+--------------+---------------
  6/5/2015     |      2
  7/5/2015     |      1
-------------------------------
```

I have tried many codes but I've failed.
I need the total change when the next day +1, and next day+1, and so..

Comment: Is that your *actual* code? It has several syntax issues and I doubt it would run at all currently

Comment: I don't understand the logic

Comment: thats not the code.. i've try many code but many error.. i just write the code.. i need your code like the correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will run forever and will increment the `$total` value by 1 everyday. Assuming this isn't a learning exercise, you'll want to swap out the initial `$startDate` value with the start date you're concerned with.

```
<?php
$startDate = new \DateTime('now');
$total = 0;

while (true) {
    $diff = date_diff($startDate, new \DateTime('now'));
    if ($diff->format('%a') !== '0') {
        $startDate->modify('+1 day');
        $total += 1;
        echo $total;
    }
}
```

If your `$startDate` is 3 days ago, the output of the code will be:

`New value: 1
New value: 2
New value: 3`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have error in PHP code. Use this:

```
<?php
$date(today);
$total;

if($date != $today)
$total += 1;
?>
```

Dollar($) sign is required in variable name.